# DNS name resolution with WebProxy in .Net HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, proxy, dns, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have a VM which connects to the net through web proxy. In the VM we have an application that makes web request to external URLs using HttpWebRequest.

We use the System.Net namespace classes HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse for making external calls. The proxy is set using the WebRequest.Proxy property.

WebRequest.Proxy = new WebProxy(...);

What is the behaviour of the underlying implementation in terms of resolving the DNS Names. There are two possibilities here:

1. Get the DNS Names and resolve to IP Address through the DNS Server and communicate with IP address through the proxy.
2. Use DNS Names all the way and the proxy takes over the IP based communication by doing the name resolution.

In our tests we are seeing the first scenario where the name resolution to IP is happening in the VM and the IP is used communicate through the proxy.

Note : The VM has access to the internet only through web proxy.

Trying to understand better on how the DNS name resolution works in presence of web proxy.

Thanks